# escape double quotes that wraps variable that contains string with html tag <p> but preservin the linebreak

Tags: php, html

I have a variable `$pesan` that contains string like this: `<p> Hi </p> <p> Hello </p>`

I'm using PHP to echo it with this code: `echo" \"$pesan\"<br/>-Anon";`

and I expected output to be like this:

> `"Hi`
>   `Hello"`
>   `-Anon`

but what I get is like this :

> `<p> Hi </p>`
>   `<p> Hello</p>`
>   `<br /> -Anon"`

and I realized it becomes like that because the html tag `<p>` is still there, so I removed it with `strip_tags($pesan);` and the output is like this `"hi Hello -Anon"`

the linebreaks is gone... so I tried adding `nl2br()` hoping to preserve the linebreaks like so `strip_tags(nl2br($pesan));`
but the output is still the same as `"Hi Hello -Anon"`

the code I use :

```
<?php

   $pesan = strip_tags(nl2br($r[pesan]));

echo"<div class='wrap-testi'>
<div class='gambar-testi'><img width='100%' src='../testimoni/$r[gambar]'/></div>
<div class='preview-testi'>
<span>\"$pesan\"<br /><br />-$r[nama]</span></div>
</div>

 ?>
```

Expected output :

`"Hi
Hello"
-anon`

please tell me how to achieve that

Comment: Do you actually want the <p> tag in your output? <p> is a block level element, meaning it acts like it has linebreaks before and after it. <p> also has top/bottom margins by default too.

Comment: not really want that <p>... but I'm using tinymce text editor for inputting message of testimony and I don't know the proper way to preserve linebreaks when I echo the variable that contains testimony in it

Comment: Don't let anyone leave HTML messages on your website - that's a security problem. Plaintext only - meaning you won't have this issue at all anyway :)

Comment: is that so? but what should I do to achieve that? if only I know how to preserve the linebreaks without html tag when I echo it

Comment: It would be rather awkward if I could drop, say, `<script src='http://example.com/myEvilScript.js'></script>` right here on stackoverflow comments - where myEvilScript grabs `document.cookie` and uploads it somewhere. That would give me full control over your account (and on your website, that might accidentally give admin access to your server, so it can be pretty severe).

Comment: Instead use [B]BB[/B], **markdown** (supported here), a subset of HTML or just plaintext. But don't reinvent these things - you'll get the parsing wrong. Use an existing safety checked comment box instead.

Comment: sorry ... I don't understand what is a safey checked comment box. and for user input, I use prepared statement, but should I strip_tags to remove the html tag before storing it to database?

Comment: This isn't an SQL injection attack - it's a script execution one. E.g: I leave a comment on your website containing, for example, a `<script>` tag. You then visit your own website (maybe to look at that new comment) and your browser *runs my script* on *your domain*. It has access to your cookies etc. The accepted answer is vulnerable to it.

Comment: By safety checked, I mean some existing platform/ library that is in use and already handles this kind of exploit correctly.

Comment: oh so you mean I shouldn't use html tags in SO questions, answer or comments and shoulnd't let people use html tag to put in comments section or any user input field in my website? do I get that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131107/discussion-between-luke-briggs-and-citra45abadi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_replace`:

```
$pesan = str_replace(["<p>", "</p>"], ["\n", ""], "<p> Hi </p> <p> Hello </p>");
```

And then `nl2br`:

```
$pesan = nl2br(str_replace(["<p>", "</p>"], ["\n", ""], "<p> Hi </p> <p> Hello </p>"));
```

`strip_tags` removes the tag, leaving only plain text.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but it not give the expected results though. or can you give me the live demo using code snippet?

Comment: using your suggestion it would be like this `$pesan = nl2br(str_replace("<p>", "\n",$r[pesan]));` right?

Comment: I forgot the closing `p` tag, see updated answer. Live version: http://tricksfortheweb.com/bab.php

Comment: thank you, I modified you code a bit like this `$pesan = nl2br(str_replace(["<p>", "</p>"],["", ""],$r[pesan]));` 
and that works well, it give the expected result

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb your answer is vulnerable because it's being used for a comment box. FWIW, there's also [https://eval.in](https://eval.in) which is commonly used to paste snippets of PHP here on SO.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, thanks for the tip about PHP snippets, I usually only did JS-type snippets using jsfiddle.

Comment: also, how is it vulnerable?

Comment: It's being used to sanitize comment boxes; `<script>`, for example, passes right through. See the comments on the OP for more info.

Comment: Well, he specifically asked for `p` tags, so I had to oblige. Of course, that is a security error, but I think you could use this and then use strip_tags to get rid of script tags, etc.

Comment: Yep and that's why I didn't downvote as it's the basic premise of the question that is dangerously flawed. I started a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131107/discussion-between-luke-briggs-and-citra45abadi) but he's not joined in yet.